# How to fix the format for date column in matrix?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have created paginated report using Power bi desktop (for report server).

The dataset has SQL similar to the following:
`select cast(datecol as date),...`

Then when I place this column in matrix then the format shown is dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00

Since it is a date I'd just like to see dd/mm/yyyy

Where can I control this?

When I click on this field, then under properties there is Number -> format but I'm not quite sure how to use this.